# OneToMany relation doesn't list elements

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I tried to get a list from using easy admin bundle items that have a OneToMany relation.

My `Member` entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Declaration", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $declarations;
```

My yaml file for Member:

```
list:
    fields:
        - { property: 'declarations', label: 'Label', template: 'type.html.twig'}
```

But I get the error

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 60 near 'declarations': Error: Invalid
>   PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or
>   SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Comment: please explain more.... what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @habibun I trying to liste all members with title of declarations

Comment: Can you please send us the whole `easy_admin.yaml` and also the `type.html.twig`. Anyway you can't display the whole object, you have to specify the property of Declaration object as said in the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html